# Договоры, ударение

Tags: ударения

Быть может уже спрашивали. не знаю, есть ли тут поиск. Если есть такой вопрос, дайте ссылку, пожалуйста. Интересует ударение и множественное число в слове "договор". Лично мне приятней "договОры". А как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: договОр - договОры (нейтр.) и дОговор - договорА (разг.).

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Если ударение в сущ. м.р. падает на последний слог, то оно не переносится на окончание, например, грубо неправильно: инженЕр - инженерА. Поэтому нет пары договОр - договорА.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно "договОры", хотя допустимо, но не желательно "договорА"

Answer (score 1):

ДоговОры и (разг.) договорА. Иногда и дОговор считают допустимым разговорным.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E4%EE%E3%EE%E2%EE%F0